# contact.php is not working. (can't receive email)

Tags: php, css, html, contact-form

I have a question about contact.php. I am able to use a contact form to send email with (Name, Phone Number, Email Address, Subject, and Message). It is sometimes sent out and sometimes not. If it is sent, all information except phone number is being sent out. I still can't figure out why it is not sending every time and not getting phone number information sent out.

Can you guys take a look of my codes?

Thanks!

[Screenshot of contact us page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1XfkF.png)

```js
<?php

if(!$_POST) exit;

// Email address verification, do not edit.
function isEmail($email) {
 return(preg_match("/^[-_.[:alnum:]]+@((([[:alnum:]]|[[:alnum:]][[:alnum:]-]*[[:alnum:]])\.)+(ad|ae|aero|af|ag|ai|al|am|an|ao|aq|ar|arpa|as|at|au|aw|az|ba|bb|bd|be|bf|bg|bh|bi|biz|bj|bm|bn|bo|br|bs|bt|bv|bw|by|bz|ca|cc|cd|cf|cg|ch|ci|ck|cl|cm|cn|co|com|coop|cr|cs|cu|cv|cx|cy|cz|de|dj|dk|dm|do|dz|ec|edu|ee|eg|eh|er|es|et|eu|fi|fj|fk|fm|fo|fr|ga|gb|gd|ge|gf|gh|gi|gl|gm|gn|gov|gp|gq|gr|gs|gt|gu|gw|gy|hk|hm|hn|hr|ht|hu|id|ie|il|in|info|int|io|iq|ir|is|it|jm|jo|jp|ke|kg|kh|ki|km|kn|kp|kr|kw|ky|kz|la|lb|lc|li|lk|lr|ls|lt|lu|lv|ly|ma|mc|md|me|mg|mh|mil|mk|ml|mm|mn|mo|mp|mq|mr|ms|mt|mu|museum|mv|mw|mx|my|mz|na|name|nc|ne|net|nf|ng|ni|nl|no|np|nr|nt|nu|nz|om|org|pa|pe|pf|pg|ph|pk|pl|pm|pn|pr|pro|ps|pt|pw|py|qa|re|ro|ru|rw|sa|sb|sc|sd|se|sg|sh|si|sj|sk|sl|sm|sn|so|sr|st|su|sv|sy|sz|tc|td|tf|tg|th|tj|tk|tm|tn|to|tp|tr|tt|tv|tw|tz|ua|ug|uk|um|us|uy|uz|va|vc|ve|vg|vi|vn|vu|wf|ws|ye|yt|yu|za|zm|zw)$|(([0-9][0-9]?|[0-1][0-9][0-9]|[2][0-4][0-9]|[2][5][0-5])\.){3}([0-9][0-9]?|[0-1][0-9][0-9]|[2][0-4][0-9]|[2][5][0-5]))$/i",$email));
}

if (!defined("PHP_EOL")) define("PHP_EOL", "\r\n");

$name     = $_POST['name'];
$phone    = $_POST['phone'];
$email    = $_POST['email'];
$subject  = $_POST['subject'];
$comments = $_POST['comments'];

if(trim($name) == '') {
 echo '<div class="error_message">Attention! You must enter your name.</div>';
 exit();
} else if(trim($phone) == '') {
 // echo '<div class="error_message">Attention! You must enter your phone number.</div>';
 // exit();
} else if(trim($email) == '') {
 echo '<div class="error_message">Attention! Please enter a valid email address.</div>';
 exit();
} else if(!isEmail($email)) {
 echo '<div class="error_message">Attention! You have enter an invalid e-mail address, try again.</div>';
 exit();
}

if(trim($subject) == '') {
 echo '<div class="error_message">Attention! Please enter a subject.</div>';
 exit();
} else if(trim($comments) == '') {
 echo '<div class="error_message">Attention! Please enter your message.</div>';
 exit();
} 

if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
 $comments = stripslashes($comments);
}


// Configuration option.
// Enter the email address that you want to emails to be sent to.
// Example $address = "joe.doe@yourdomain.com";

$address = "XXXXXX@gmail.com";


// Configuration option.
// i.e. The standard subject will appear as, "You've been contacted by John Doe."

// Example, $e_subject = '$name . ' has contacted you via Your Website.';

$e_subject = 'You\'ve been contacted by ' . $name . '.';


// Configuration option.
// You can change this if you feel that you need to.
// Developers, you may wish to add more fields to the form, in which case you must be sure to add them here.

$e_body = "You have been contacted by $name with regards to $subject, their additional message is as follows." . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;
$e_content = "\"$comments\"" . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;
$e_reply = "You can contact $name via email, $email or via phone, $phone";

$msg = wordwrap( $e_body . $e_content . $e_reply, 70 );

$headers = "From: $email" . PHP_EOL;
$headers .= "Reply-To: $email" . PHP_EOL;
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0" . PHP_EOL;
$headers .= "Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8" . PHP_EOL;
$headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable" . PHP_EOL;

if(mail($address, $e_subject, $msg, $headers)) {

 // Email has sent successfully, echo a success page.

 echo "<fieldset>";
 echo "<div id='success_page'>";
 echo "<h1>Email Sent Successfully.</h1>";
 echo "<p>Thank you <strong>$name</strong>, your message has been submitted to us.</p>";
 echo "</div>";
 echo "</fieldset>";

} else {

 echo 'ERROR!';

}
```

```css
.contact_form {
  overflow:hidden;
  margin:50px 0 25px;
 }
 .overlay .contact_details {
  color:#fff !important;
 }
 .contact_form textarea {
  height:133px !important;
 }
 .contact_form .form-control {
  margin-bottom:10px;
  height:62px;
  border-color:#dddddd;
  box-shadow:none;
 }
 #contactform fieldset {
  padding:10px;
  border:1px solid #eee;
  -webkit-border-radius:5px;
  -moz-border-radius:5px;
 }
 #contactform legend {
  padding:7px 10px; 
  font-weight:bold; 
  color:#000; 
  border:1px solid #eee; 
  -webkit-border-radius:5px; 
  -moz-border-radius:5px; 
  margin-bottom:0 !important; 
  margin-bottom:20px;
 }
 #contactform span.required{ 
  font-size: 13px; 
  color: #ff0000;
 }
```

```html
<div class="contact_form">
                <div class="general-title">
            <h2>Contact Us</h2>
                </div>
                <div id="message"></div>
                <form id="contactform" action="contact.php" name="contactform" method="post">
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
     <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Name"> 
                    <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" class="form-control" placeholder="Phone Number">
     <input type="text" name="email" id="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email Address"> 
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
     <input type="text" name="subject" id="subject" class="form-control" placeholder="Subject"> 
     <textarea class="form-control" name="comments" id="comments" rows="6" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
     <button type="submit" value="SEND" id="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary pull-right">CONTACT US</button>
    </div>
            </form> 
            </div>
            <!-- end contact-form -->
```

Comment: in place of echo "Error"; 
Do print_r(error_get_last()); and see what error its printing and share...

Comment: What is the error you are getting ?

Comment: let us know if you are sending an email from localhost.

Comment: now email got sent out, but there is still no phone number shown up. @Punit sending thru the hosting company server.